# Convert received data bytes in serial to hex text

Tags: tty, serial-port, busybox, hex, od

Hi now I write bytes data (for eg, **`\x00\x11\x22`**) from my PC to serial port of my device running unix at the ttyS1 port. I am able to print the data using either

```
cat /dev/ttyS1
od -x < /dev/ttyS1
```

both works, 
but with cat I get "▒▒" printed.
With od, i see some data bytes:

```
0000000     00fe
0000001
```

Which is not what i sent (001122Hex).

How can I get the correct hex display?

**EDIT**:
tty permission set:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS1 speed 115200 cs8 -cstopb -parenb -echo time 3 min 0
```

**EDIT2**:
Something weird is happening I am not sure why. I tried to send different data:
"1049" which my program then sends as "\x10\x49". od returns:

```
0000000    4910
0000002
```

Seems it reversed the bytes. But what I don't get now is if I have repeated number like "\x11\x49" at once the data becomes corrupted. Seems like all repeated value like x11, x00, x22, are translated wrongly for some reason. And,
any value over 8 also wrongly translated. Any idea why? Use either hexdump or od give same result.

Comment: Anybody have any idea why this problem occur? Or do I have a buggy "od" binary or something?

Answer (score 1):

od shows that you are just receiving 254 Decimal here, the left par is the "line number".

I think the problem here is how you send the data, or your /dev/ttyS1 permissions, could you develop more on that part ?

Also what do you see if you use xxd -r ?

Comment: Hi. I am aware that left part is "index" or "line number". what I don't get is why I get 00fe, when I am sending a "Hexadecimal packet" of value \x00\x11\x22 from my Windows PC. Also i updated the stty that i used in my question.

Comment: Also, if I am sending "\x00", nothing is printed by od.

Comment: My unix distro (busybox) dont have xxd installed.

Comment: Strange then, how do you exactly send the data ?

Comment: I make my own software using Qt (C++). Where I have a text input so I can type hex value as text "001122" then i convert this string to UTF8 and convert to QByteArray and write it to the serialport object.

Comment: I think I have a kind of endian issues here. Hmm...